# MySQL - Take Specific row being a value NULL or max, not just column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm searching how to make a select with 2-3 columns and take the results with the parameter in one column as NULL, otherwise if there is no NULL for a username, take the max date.

My problem is that in the results, the ipaddr is from the max stoptime row, if there is no NULL row i get the ipaddr correctly

Is important for me for can search by user.

Lets take a look to my database format:

```
    username        stoptime              ipaddr
    peter       2012-10-16 00:00:00      1.1.1.1
    obama       2014-03-12 00:00:00      1.1.1.2
    peter       2013-10-16 00:00:00      1.1.1.3
    obama             NULL               1.1.1.4
```

When i launch:

```
SELECT username,case when MAX(stoptime is NULL)=0 then max(stoptime) end as stoptime,ipaddr
    FROM tb
    WHERE username LIKE "%OBAM%" group by username;
```

In this example i expect to take from my query this results:

```
obama             NULL               1.1.1.4
```

Instead this i take this:

```
obama             NULL               1.1.1.2
```

Thanks!

Comment: what if you have several records with `NULL` which record you want to get?

Comment: There wont be duplicates with with the same username and stoptime as NULL, until there is no stoptime, it wont créate another row with NULL on stoptime.

Comment: why don't you put time value there then? or maybe create another column `starttime`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `group by` incorrectly.  In particular, you have columns in the `select` that are not in the `group by`.  MySQL specifically discourages this (see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html)).

The simplest way to do what you want is:

```
SELECT username,
       (case when max(stoptime is null) = 0
             then max(stoptime)
        end) as stoptime,
       substring_index(group_concat(ipaddr order by (stoptime is null) desc, stoptime desc), ',', 1) as ipaddr
FROM tb
WHERE username LIKE "%OBAM%"
group by username;
```

However, there are some limitations with this approach -- such as the size of the intermediate string for concatenation.  There are other methods, but this works in many cases.

Comment: so for data sample provided OP what value do we get in `stoptime`? it seems  `coalesce(max(stoptime), 0)` will return `2014-03-12 00:00:00`? am I wrong?

Comment: Thank you very much, this had solved my problem with the ipaddr value, but now in the stoptime value i get the last stoptime, can i change it with another static value or something?
Thank's again

Comment: I'm trying to get NULL instead of the max stoptime if i search for %obam% and if i search for %peter% the max stoptime, can someone tell me how?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you helped me a lot, i had to make some changes, now i have to concatenate this query with some left joins thank you very much, this is my finnal query: just im afraid for the size of the intermediate string for concatenation, it can be with hundreds, probably with thousands of different results wich problem can i get if its too long? how much is too long?

```
SELECT username, coalesce(max(stoptime)) as lasstop,
   substring_index(group_concat(ipaddr order by starttime desc), ',', 1) as ipaddr,
   substring_index(group_concat(stoptime order by starttime desc), ',' ,1) as stopt,
   CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN stoptime IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0  
   THEN MAX(stoptime) END as x FROM tb WHERE username LIKE "%%" group by username;
```

Best regards.